# What is the difference between << variants in Vagrant heredoc?

Tags: ruby, heredoc

I've seen these examples for Heredocs in `Vagrantfile`s:

```
$myscript1 = <<SCRIPT
    echo "test <<"
SCRIPT

$myscript2 = <<-SCRIPT
    echo "test <<-"
SCRIPT

$myscript3 = <<~SCRIPT
    echo "test <<~"
SCRIPT
```

Could anyone explain with examples what is the difference between these variants?

Are there more variants for inline Heredocs?

Comment: doc for [heredocs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents+-28heredocs-29)

Comment: ^ The last two code blocks of the heredocs documentation are broken since the Ruby 2.6.4 documentation. I suggest looking at the [2.6.3 documentation for heredocs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) which is the last one that correctly displays the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [heredoc documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) pointed out in the comments:

> If you are writing a large block of text you may use a “here document” or “heredoc”:
>
> ```
> expected_result = <<HEREDOC
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
> HEREDOC
> ```
>
> The heredoc starts on the line following `<<HEREDOC` and ends with the next line that starts with `HEREDOC`. The result includes the ending newline.
>
> You may use any identifier with a heredoc, but all-uppercase identifiers are typically used.
>
> You may indent the ending identifier if you place a “-” after <<:
>
> ```
>   expected_result = <<-INDENTED_HEREDOC
> This would contain specially formatted text.
>
> That might span many lines
>   INDENTED_HEREDOC
> ```
>
> Note that the while the closing identifier may be indented, the content is always treated as if it is flush left. If you indent the content those spaces will appear in the output.
>
> To have indented content as well as an indented closing identifier, you can use a “squiggly” heredoc, which uses a “~” instead of a “-” after <<:
>
> ```
>   expected_result = <<~SQUIGGLY_HEREDOC
>     This would contain specially formatted text.
>
>     That might span many lines
>   SQUIGGLY_HEREDOC
> ```
>
> The indentation of the least-indented line will be removed from each line of the content. Note that empty lines and lines consisting solely of literal tabs and spaces will be ignored for the purposes of determining indentation, but escaped tabs and spaces are considered non-indentation characters.